# Enable INT1 in LSMDSRX Sudden acceleration occurs interfaced with ESP32S3 and capure image

Tags: c++, arduino-esp32

> I am trying to enable the INT1 interrupt when sudden acceleration occurs and capture the image to save into SD card.
> I am facing problem of "Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled."
> I need suggestion to correct this code//
> ESP32 interfaced with LSMDSRX and camera 5640 via i2c
> I tried:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SD_MMC.h>
#include <esp_camera.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "soc/soc.h"           // Disable brownout problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  // Disable brownout problems

int value;
#define LSM6DSR_ADDRESS 0x6B  // I2C address of the sensor
#define CTRL1_XL_REG 0x10     // Register address for accelerometer control
#define CTRL2_G_REG 0x11      // Register address for gyroscope control
#define ACCEL_DATA_REG 0x28   // Register address for accelerometer data (LSB)
#define GYRO_DATA_REG 0x22    // Register address for accelerometer data (LSB)
#define INT1_CTRL_REG 0x0D    // Register address for INT1_CTRL

#define INT1_PIN 34  // This could be any digital pin on the ESP32 for INT1
volatile bool suddenAccelerationDetected = false;

byte receivedData[6];

int16_t accelX;
int16_t accelY;
int16_t accelZ;
double x3;
double y3;
double z3;
double Xarray[2];
int threshold = 5;

#define minVal -8315
#define maxVal 8315

#define FILE_NAME_SIZE 100
#define FILE_NAME_ADDR 0  // EEPROM address to store the image name
#define MAX_IMAGES 1000
char fileName[FILE_NAME_SIZE] = "/image.jpg";    // Default image name
File file;

// Define the pins for the camera module
#define CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE  // Has PSRAM
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM 15
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM 20
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM 19
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM 16
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM 17
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM 18
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM 12
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM 10
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM 8
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM 9
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM 11
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM 6
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM 7
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM 13


void IRAM_ATTR eventISR(){
  suddenAccelerationDetected = true;
  detachInterrupt(INT1_PIN);
}

// Declare a 32-bit integer aligned to a 4-byte boundary
uint32_t __attribute__((aligned(4))) alignedVariable;

void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Start serial communication for debugging
  initCamera();
  // Initialize the WDT with a timeout of 3 seconds (adjust as needed)
  esp_task_wdt_init(1, true);
  // Initialize SD card
  SD_MMC.setPins(39, 38, 40);
  if (!SD_MMC.begin("/sdcard", true, false, 20000, 5)) {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }

  // Turn-off the 'brownout detector'
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);

  Wire.begin(4,5);          // Initialize I2C communication
  Serial.println("SD card Initialzed");
  initializeSensor();
  Serial.println("Sensor Initialzed");
  pinMode(INT1_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(INT1_PIN, eventISR, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  // Reset the WDT timer periodically in your loop
  // esp_task_wdt_reset();
  // captureAndSaveImage();
  readAndPrintSensorData();
  delay(2000);
  // if (suddenAccelerationDetected) {
  //   suddenAccelerationDetected = false;
  //   handleSuddenAcceleration(); 
  // }
  // delay(1000); // Delay for 1 second before the next reading


  if(suddenAccelerationDetected){
    Serial.println("Interrupt!");
    captureAndSaveImage();
    delay(15000); //debouncing
    suddenAccelerationDetected = false;
    attachInterrupt(INT1_PIN, eventISR, RISING);   
  }
}

void handleLSMInterrupt() {
  suddenAccelerationDetected = true;
  captureAndSaveImage();
}



void initializeSensor() {
  // Configure accelerometer settings
  Serial.println("Sensor Initialzation procress on-going 1");
  Wire.beginTransmission(LSM6DSR_ADDRESS);
  Serial.println("Sensor Initialzation procress on-going 2");
  Wire.write(CTRL1_XL_REG);
  Serial.println("Sensor Initialzation procress on-going 3");
  // Set the accelerometer scale to ±2g (you can choose ±4g, ±8g, or ±16g as well)
  Wire.write(0x18);
  Serial.println("Sensor Initialzation procress on-going 4");
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Serial.println("Sensor Initialzation procress on-going 5");
  
}

void readAndPrintSensorData() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(LSM6DSR_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(ACCEL_DATA_REG);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(LSM6DSR_ADDRESS, 6); // Request 6 bytes (X, Y, Z accelerometer data)
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    receivedData[i] = Wire.read();
  }
  accelX =  (receivedData[1] << 8) | receivedData[0] ; // Combine LSB and MSB
  accelY =  (receivedData[3] << 8) | receivedData[2] ;
  accelZ =  (receivedData[5] << 8) | receivedData[4] ;
  
  int xAng = map(accelX, minVal, maxVal, -90, 90);
  int yAng = map(accelY, minVal, maxVal, -90, 90);
  int zAng = map(accelZ, minVal, maxVal, -90, 90);
  x3 = RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -zAng) + PI);
  y3 = RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-xAng, -zAng) + PI);
  z3 = RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -xAng) + PI);

  Xarray[0] = Xarray[1];
  Xarray[1] = x3;
  float Xaxis_difff = abs(Xarray[1] -  Xarray[0]);

  Serial.print("X:");
  Serial.println(x3);
  Serial.print("Angle difference: ");
  Serial.println(Xaxis_difff);

   if (Xaxis_difff > threshold) {
    suddenAccelerationDetected = true;
  }
}


void captureAndSaveImage() {
  // camera_fb_t* fb = NULL;
  camera_fb_t * fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  // fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Failed to capture image");
    return;
  }

  // Save the image with the given file name to SD card
  file = SD_MMC.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  if (file) {
    file.write(fb->buf, fb->len);
    file.close();
    Serial.println("Image saved to SD card");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to save image to SD card");
  }
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
}

void initCamera(){
 // OV2640 camera module
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST;

  if (psramFound()) {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 1;
     Serial.println("Camera initialized with QSXGA");
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
  // Camera init[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cE8P.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1VBZ.png)
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    ESP.restart();
  } 
}
```

> Sensor Initialzed